# Using javascript variable inside inline javascript expression

Tags: javascript, inline, thymeleaf

Is is possible, on a inline javascript block in a thymeleaf template, use the value of a variable inside a expression like that:

```
var target = select.data("target");
var value = /*[[ ... ]]*/;
```

the content for `...` in `value` should be something like that:

```
${command.get('...')
```

where the parameter for the method `.get(...)` should be the value of variable `target`.

Comment: you mean like `command.get(target)` ?

Comment: that do not work. this: `var value = /*[[${command.get(target)}]]*/;` was evaluated to this: `var valur=null;`.

Comment: and `target` is associated to a html select element. when I have more of one element in page, this not work properly at all.